# Converting first page of the pdf file to JPG using imagemagick in bluehost using PHP

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have a pdf file and I need to convert the first page only to JPG, I used this code:

```
<?php
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pdf/7a41272307d844006ce1d07db8ee951e_PRO 1.pdf';

$im = new \Imagick($file);
$im->setIteratorIndex(0); // just use first page
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_WHITE); // Other alpha options are available, see Imagick PHP documentation
$im->setImageColorspace(\Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB); // Other colorspaces are available, see Imagick PHP documentation
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white'); // Set transparent background elements to this color
$im->setFormat('JPG'); // Format, a wide variety is supported
$im->scaleImage(350, 350, true); // WxH + force aspect (true/false)

// To just output the raw image data to browser:
$im->destroy();
?>

<img src="<?=$im;?>">
```

and this what I am getting:

����JFIFHH�� ICC_PROFILE mntrRGB XYZ acspAPPL���- desc�|cprtx(wtpt�bkpt�rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRCgTRCbTRCdesc"Artifex Software sRGB ICC Profile"Artifex Software sRGB ICC ProfiletextCopyright Artifex Software 2011XYZ �Q�XYZ XYZ o�8��XYZ b����XYZ $����curv #(-27;@EJOTY^chmrw|������������������������� %+28>ELRY`gnu|����������������&/8AKT]gqz������������!-8COZfr~���������� -;HUcq~��������� +:IXgw��������'7HYj{�������+=Oat�������2FZn�������  % : O d y � � � � � �  ' = T j � � � � � �"9Qi������*C\u����� & @ Z t � � � � �.Id���� %A^z���� &Ca~����1Om����&Ed����#Cc����'Ij����4Vx���&Il����Ae

Why I am getting these weird characters? and how to fix this issue?

Comment: You mean I should make it to save the image in the server and then show it?

Comment: Post your original PDF file.